# How to correctly call the API endpoint with Python 3 without getting error 500?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, endpoint, pancakeswap

I am following the instruction as per the API documentation and enquiring the following endpoint:

```
summary = 'https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/summary'
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
{'error': {'code': 500, 'message': 'GraphQL error: panic processing query: only derived fields can lead to multiple children here'}}
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

summary = 'https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/summary'

def get_data(endpoint):
    data = requests.get(endpoint).json()
    print(data)


get_data(summary)
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with the server. I even tried to use their own Run button on their website and got the same message:

[image]

When running other API calls, there was no error, so I think there is just an issue with this specific API call.

Comment: According https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-info-api/blob/develop/v2-documentation.md other calls have this problem too.

Comment: Actually - you are right - there are some other calls that are having problems too.
When I checked - this call seemed to be working: `https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/tokens`